# Обнулить значение в localstorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, localstorage

Помогите пожалуйста обнулить значение в localstorage при помощи функции resetStorage()

На страничке есть кнопка, при клике по которой увеличивается значение counter в localstorage. Так же на страничке есть 2 кнопки. при клике по #button1 происходит обнуление counter, а при клике по #button2 обнуление не происходит. Мне нужно чтобы при клике по #button2 тоже происходило обнуление.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wexa95L2/1/)

html:

```
<div ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="lsController">
        <button ng-click="$storage.counter = $storage.counter + 1">{{$storage.counter}}</button>
        <button ng-click="$storage.counter = 0" id="button1">reset counter</button>
        <button ng-click="resetStorage()"       id="button2">reset counter</button>
    </div>          
</div>
```

js:

```
angular.module('App', ['ngStorage'])
    .controller('lsController', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
        $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
            counter: 0
        });  

        $scope.resetStorage = function () {
            console.log('reset');
            $storage.counter = 0;
        };         
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular
.module('App', ['ngStorage'])
.controller('lsController', function ($scope, $localStorage) {
    $scope.$storage = $localStorage.$default({
        counter: 0
    });  

    $scope.resetStorage = function () {
        console.log('reset');
        $scope.$storage.counter = 0; // $scope забыли )))
    };         
});
```